# Many animations in one mathematica file => Aborted

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, dynamic

I have a Mathematica notebook and I am doing several animations in this file.

All have the form:

```
animationi=Animate[...]
```

After the 10th animation (all other animations are paused ) I cannot produce the 11th animation but I get `$Aborted`...

I cannot manipulate the file anymore and there is an alert window opening for a millisecond and then closes again. I have to close the file and copy everything out of it to continue working on the file without the animations.

Can you tell me what can I do to avoid that I get the `$Aborted` message and that my file crashes? Are the animations memory intensive such that my file crashes after a few animation commands?

Comment: where is your code? We cannot help you without an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ten animations are lot to have running at once. From what you report, it is pushing your system to its limit. Try deleting the display cells (*not* the code cells) of some of animations that will not be visible when in area where you current working is visible in the notebook window. My experience suggests to me that animation cells put a load on the front end even when they appear paused and are not currently visible on the screen.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem ;)